# error cannot create directory ~\.android\.android in android studio while running the application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Concerned error

```
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Cannot create directory ~\.android\.android
```

###### OS: Windows 10 Home Build 19043

###### Android Studio Version: 2020.3.1 Patch 3

full build log:
http://p.ip.fi/m1-O

###### Things tried till now:

- reinstalling Android Studio completely.
- changing java versions (have tried 8, 11, 16, 17) gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

This path is defined by the environment variable : ANDROID_USER_HOME

Try to define it to a path your current user has full permissions.

Ref : Environment variables related to Android : https://developer.android.com/tools/variables